# How to open XML tree in iframe

Tags: javascript, c#, html, xml, iframe

I'm trying to open an XML URL in an iframe.  After a button click, a URL (`url`) will be retrieved from a database and passed into an iframe (`Xml_iframe`) to display on a page.

If I do the following:

```
void ButtonClick(string url) {
    Xml_iframe.Src = url;
}
```

...then my iframe will hide all the tags and show the raw text as one long string.  This is not what I want.

**How do I display the XML file as a tree?**  If I open it in a new tab, like with:

```
void ButtonClick(string url) {
    string scrp = "<script type='text/javascript'>window.open('" + url + "');</script>";
    Response.Write(scrp);
}
```

...then the browser knows to display it in XML-tree format, complete with collapsible tags and color-coded elements.  In this case, it's in a new window, not my iframe.  **How do I mimic this behavior in my iframe?**

Comment: what's the file type in url?

Comment: the url is http://www.someWebsite.com/someXmlFile.xml (not literally).  It is an XML file.